# Parse a long text to a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text

I would like to plot race results using python, the txt file is not a CSV but a long text file in a single line.
Ex:

1. ESCALE (AIX ATHLE PROVENCE)34'49", 2. BAYARD (LPM)36'13", 3. MARTINEZ (MAIRIE AIX-EN-PROVENCE)36'20", 4. RACCA (RUNNING CONSEIL MARSEILLE)36'28", 5. FERNANDEZ 36'31", 6. PAMPLONA 37'27", 7. DUVAL 37'51", 8. SEGUIN 38'50", 9. SAHLI (ACP MARSEILLE)38'56", 10. OUANDA (USC SEPTEMES)39'20", 11. DE-ABREU (AUBAGNE TRIATHLON)39'34"

I would like to parse it do a dataframe. With columns Rank, Name, time.
Any idea how to achieve that?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You should first parse your text into a list of results, then use a regex to parse each result into the three parts, then put the results in a dataframe. Try it out and when/if you get stuck, come back and ask a question about the step that's giving you trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much, managed to do that :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.